# How to update UI when invoke method failed

Tags: c#, winforms

set visible = true then message box show it is false

```
 delegate void LoadLastDeptSettingDelegate(String last_dept);
        private void LoadLastDeptSetting(String last_dept)
        {
            //MessageBox.Show("last dept " + last_dept + this.InvokeRequired.ToString());
            if (this.InvokeRequired)
            {
                //this.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate() { LoadLastDeptSetting(last_dept); }));
                this.Invoke(new LoadLastDeptSettingDelegate(this.LoadLastDeptSetting), new
                object[] { last_dept });
            }
            else
            {
                  grpPeriod.Visible = true;
                  MessageBox.Show("before 3 " + this.grpPeriod.Visible.ToString());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Visible` property indicates the control's *actual* visibility.

If one of the control's ancestors, or the entire form, is not visible, it will always return `false`.